# How can I encrypt a value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
     primaryKey int unsigned NOT NULL,
     emailAddress mediumblob NOT NULL
);
```

What attribute (like NOT NULL) can I use so that the emailAddress would be encrypted?
I would greatly appreciate the help. I tried encrypt() but that's giving me errors.

Comment: You can use `PASSWORD('mypass');` but why not do it with your language of choice?

Comment: Encryption is not a concept defined in your table, it is a mechanism used as part of your data manipulation. You can create triggers to isolate the encryption process to the db server (insert/update unencrypted data, trigger modifies it), but again, that is simply an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

if you looking to encrypt data where you can decrypt it later then you should use `ES_ENCRYPT() AND AES_DECRYPT()`

According to the Manual

```
AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string. AES_DECRYPT() decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original string. .
```

[MySQL 5.1 Doc: AES_ENCRYPT() / AES_DECRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html)

you can use it like this

```
INSERT INTO table (email)VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('myemail', 'secrectkey' ))
```

to read the data that is encrypted  you can do this

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(email, 'secrectkey' ) FROM table
```

where secrectkey is really a secret value that only authorized users should have access to

But if you are looking for hashing "a one way hash that can't be read back in plain text" you can use one of the following functions

```
MD5('myemail');
OR
PASSWORD('myemail');
OR 
SHA1('myemail');
```

Then your table length depends on the encryption method you use. you can use VARCHAR() if the length of your encrypted message changes. If you know that you will be using fixed length I would use CHAR(exact_length)

Again the length will depend on the method you use.

Answer (score 0):

You have the complete list of encryption functions supported by MySQL DBMS on this official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html).